# Run dhclient on startup

Tags: ubuntu, dhclient, netplan

I have this server that loses its network config on reboots, it's running Ubuntu Server 18.04, I tried the `netplan` commands but none generated a thing, maybe it's because the interface isn't even there until I run `dhclient`, only then the system brings the interface up and DHCP assigns it its static address. On boot, only the loopback interface is brought up automatically.

Instead of going crazy trying to decipher `netplan`--which most likely I'm not going to use much since I loathe Ubuntu for some reason--I'd like to go around it and just automatically run `dhclient` upon boot.

Would something like a cron job work? Do I need to assign special permissions somewhere or have special permissions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is your interface configured? Can you edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use dhcpcd.
If you are on systemd distro(not sure what ubuntu uses,systemd or init);

```
#systemctl enable --now dhcpcd
```

make sure you don't have another network daemon enabled though (eg networkmanager).

Comment: Could you explain how this would help?

Comment: dhcpcd is a DHCP service(daemon). The question was about run dhcpclient at startup.